# Reload aspx page after data is saved to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

This is the code through which i am trying to save data into excel but after the data is saved, the page freezes and cannot redirect to a different page.

```
 public void Save(Literal L) 
  { 
      Response.ContentType =

      "application/ms-excel";
          Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.xls");
          Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
          Response.Write("<head>");
          Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;  charset=windows-1252\">");
          Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]>");
          Response.Write("<xml>");
          Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
          Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
          Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
          //this line names the worksheet
          Response.Write("<x:Name>Report</x:Name>");
          Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
          //these 2 lines are what works the magic
          Response.Write("<x:Panes>");
          Response.Write("</x:Panes>");
          Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
          Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
          Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
          Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
          Response.Write("</xml>");
          Response.Write("<![endif]-->");
          Response.Write("</head>");
          Response.Write("<body>");
          Response.Write(L.Text);
          Response.Write("</body>");
          Response.Write("</html>"); }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you trying to ask...Please elaborate your problem a bit more..

Comment: This is the code through which i am tryin to save data into excel but after the data is saved, the page freezes and cannot redirect to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call `Response.Redirect("currentpage url here");` at the end of the `save()` function.

Call the Response.End() at the end of all statements in your save method.

```
public void Save(Literal L) 
{ 
  Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
  Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
  Response.Write("<head>");
  ------------------
  --------------------

 Response.End();//call this
}
```

Comment: call `Response.End()` after all `Response.Write()` statements

Comment: Yes i did but the execution of the page stops.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines of code

```
          public void Save(Literal L) 
  { 
      Response.ContentType =

      "application/ms-excel";
          Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.xls");
          Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
          Response.Write("<head>");
          Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;  charset=windows-1252\">");
          Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]>");
          Response.Write("<xml>");
          Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
          Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
          Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
          //this line names the worksheet
          Response.Write("<x:Name>Report</x:Name>");
          Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
          //these 2 lines are what works the magic
          Response.Write("<x:Panes>");
          Response.Write("</x:Panes>");
          Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
          Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
          Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
          Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
          Response.Write("</xml>");
          Response.Write("<![endif]-->");
          Response.Write("</head>");
          Response.Write("<body>");
          Response.Write(L.Text);
          Response.Write("</body>");
          Response.Write("</html>");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Data has been saved');window.location.replace('pagename.aspx');</script>");

         }
```